# How to configure proxy correctly to make post requests in Angular/Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have an Angular application where I have a proxy configured, which routes my api calls to my gateway and from my gateway to my respective microservice. So far it looks like it works at least the routing part. But when I make my request, I am getting an error: 405 this method (post) not allowed. But in my Backend the api I am calling is an post request. I do not really Understand why this happens, I guess something with my proxy or my gateway is maybe broken?

Gateway and Microservice was generated via jhipster and not changed at all accept the urls in the microservice to call the method.

my Proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/api"
    },
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
  "/moniestaproduction": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/moniestaproduction": "/moniestaproduction"
    },
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

My Backend Method in my Microservice:

```
@PostMapping("/materials-add")
    public ResponseEntity<MaterialDTO> createMaterial(@RequestBody MaterialDTO materialDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Material : {}", materialDTO);
        if (materialDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new material cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        MaterialDTO result = materialService.save(materialDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/materials/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

I tried adding this line on class lvl but it did not work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
```

this is how I call the api from Angular:

```
addMaterial(material: MaterialModel): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.post<MaterialModel>(environment.api_server_url + 'moniestaproduction/api/materials-add', material, {
      observe: 'response'
    });
    console.log("HALLO RESPONSE")
  }
```

Edit:

I tried to access via postman and still it did not work same error: 405

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it the url I had to use was `http://localhost:8080/services/moniestaproduction/api/materials-add`. I think gateway has added the services part I do not really know where and how but now it works.

Comment: The `/services`prefix is configured in `zuul.prefix` property of `src/main/resources/config/application.yml`

Comment: hey thank you :) Now I have learned something else